"The application did not respond" when running "Purge" command with a discord bot. Why is this happening?
Everytime I run my command "purge" on my Discord bot, I keep seeing "The application did not respond" after the command runs and deletes the limited messages. I'm using discord.app_commands (I believe) and tree for my commands so they can run as slash commands.
What happens after running the "purge" slash command.
Here are my imports:
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
from asyncio import sleep

Here is the command:
@tree.command(
    name="purge",
    description="Deletes a specified number of messages from the channel."
)
async def purge(interaction, limit: int):
    try:
        if interaction.user.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
            await interaction.channel.purge(limit=limit + 1)
            await sleep(2)
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"{limit} messages deleted!", ephemeral=True)

        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("You don't have permission to use this command.", ephemeral=True)
    except discord.errors.NotFound:
        # Handle the case where the interaction is not found
        await interaction.response.send_message("An error occurred while processing the command. Please try again later.", ephemeral=True)
    except discord.errors.Forbidden:
        # Handle the case where the bot doesn't have permission to perform the action
        await interaction.response.send_message("I don't have permission to perform this action.", ephemeral=True)
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle any other exceptions that might occur
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"An unexpected error occurred: {str(e)}", ephemeral=True)

This error occurs ONLY when I run purge, no other command I have has caused this. I did "/purge" with a limit block of any integer, and after the bot deletes the specific amount of messages, I expected it to appear with "{limit} messages deleted!" but instead, it says "The application did not respond." I tried making the bot wait 2 seconds before sending the message, but it didn't work either.
Also, the Traceback from my server console:
2024-04-09 00:22:43 ERROR    discord.app_commands.tree Ignoring exception in command 'purge'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/bot_commands.py", line 27, in purge
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"{limit} messages deleted!", ephemeral=True)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/interactions.py", line 801, in send_message
    await adapter.create_interaction_response(
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/webhook/async_.py", line 219, in request
    raise NotFound(response, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 828, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/bot_commands.py", line 33, in purge
    await interaction.response.send_message("An error occurred while processing the command. Please try again later.", ephemeral=True)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/interactions.py", line 801, in send_message
    await adapter.create_interaction_response(
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/webhook/async_.py", line 219, in request
    raise NotFound(response, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1248, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 853, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 846, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'purge' raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction


You will have to use interaction.defer() in the starting of function as interaction can be replied within 3 sec and purging would take more than 3 sec. But using interaction.defer() would increase that 3 sec limit to 15 min.
Updated code:
@tree.command(
    name="purge",
    description="Deletes a specified number of messages from the channel."
)
async def purge(interaction, limit: int):
    await interaction.defer() # here
    try:
        if interaction.user.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
            await interaction.channel.purge(limit=limit + 1)
            await sleep(2)
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"{limit} messages deleted!", ephemeral=True)

        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("You don't have permission to use this command.", ephemeral=True)
    except discord.errors.NotFound:
        # Handle the case where the interaction is not found
        await interaction.response.send_message("An error occurred while processing the command. Please try again later.", ephemeral=True)
    except discord.errors.Forbidden:
        # Handle the case where the bot doesn't have permission to perform the action
        await interaction.response.send_message("I don't have permission to perform this action.", ephemeral=True)
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle any other exceptions that might occur
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"An unexpected error occurred: {str(e)}", ephemeral=True)

Docs refrence:

interaction.defer()


There's no way around it? Like, what if I want to maximize the usability of the bot, like most popular ones?

For example, Maki's quick-functioning "prune" command also used to delete messages?

Why do u want a way around? It is the only way to increase the time for responding interation

I mean, isn't there a way to make sure that the bot responds quick without rate limitation? I'm not very good at coding, so most of this stuff, I don't know how to do. Also, I heard that sharding helps, but making Cogs for the bot work better? (This bot is only in two servers).

Sharding does make the bot faster, but it is effective only when your bot is in 100-200 servers. Purging takes sometime to delete the messages and it won't get you rate limited. This is the most effective way, as long as I know.
